# SimpleDateFormat hour string off-by-one on certain *dates*. How? Why?

Tags: java, android, calendar, simpledateformat, gregorian-calendar

I'm using `SimpleDateFormat` to turn my `GregorianCalendar` instances into nice strings. I'm having a weird issue where in certain **dates** the **time** string is off by one, but not always.

Normally, if my `GregorianCalendar` has values like `HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=11` then I get a string like "1:11 AM". But then I change the `YEAR`, `MONTH`, or `DAY` and now `HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=11` gives me the string "**2:11 AM**".

This is my time to string formatting function (datetime is the `GregorianCalendar`):

```
public String toTimeString() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Datetime: "+ datetime.toString() + "Formatted as: " + SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance(SimpleDateFormat.SHORT).format(datetime.getTime()));
    return SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance(SimpleDateFormat.SHORT).format(datetime.getTime());
}
```

This gives me these logs:

Working good at first:

```
Datetime: java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1426637512725,areFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=GMT,firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2015,MONTH=2,WEEK_OF_YEAR=12,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=18,DAY_OF_YEAR=77,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=11,SECOND=52,MILLISECOND=725,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]
Formatted as: 1:11 AM
```

then I change the month from March to April (year and day do the same) and now this:

```
Datetime: java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1429315912725,areFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=GMT,firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2015,MONTH=3,WEEK_OF_YEAR=16,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=18,DAY_OF_YEAR=108,DAY_OF_WEEK=7,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=11,SECOND=52,MILLISECOND=725,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]
Formatted as: 2:11 AM
```

How could this possibly be?

This off-by-one behavior only seems to happen in future months, not this month or last. 2015 and 2016 are fine, but 2017 causes it the problem, too. The actual date seems to trigger it when it's a week or more into the future (regardless of year).

I can change year, month, and date in different UI widgets, switching the time-string formatting from normal to off-by-one and back. I control the hour with a `TimePicker` that calls the string formatter on `TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener()`. I don't think it's relevant, since it works when month and day are set to some values, but here is that code just in case. As you can see, there is some off-by-one handling, as `GregorianCalendar` stores `HOUR_OF_DAY` as a 0-23 value, and the `TimePicker` uses values 1-24 matching what the widget actually displays. I think I've done this right, but would be happy to find out the problem is a mistake here.

```
private void setUpTimePicker() {
    timePicker.setCurrentHour(schedule.getHourOfDay() + 1);
    timePicker.setCurrentMinute(schedule.getMinute());

    timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            schedule.setHourOfDay(hourOfDay - 1);
            schedule.setMinute(minute);
            timeText.setText(schedule.toTimeString());
        }
    });
}
```

The time of day formatted to a string is always right (0 = 1am, 17 = 5pm, etc for every hour of the day) or always wrong (0 = 2am, 17 = 6pm, ect for every hour of the day) based on the other calendar fields. **The consistency makes me think that it's not a thread issue**.

Could it be a **timezone issue** like every other similar question? I can't imagine how. My `GregorianCalandar` instances are always created with this function:

```
public static TimeZone TIMEZONE = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");

private static GregorianCalendar makeCalendar(){
    GregorianCalendar now = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance(TIMEZONE); 
    now.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY); 
    return now;
}
```

**Any thoughts would be very appreciated!** I've exhausted everything that I can think of, including sleeping on it for a few days. **Thanks in advance to anyone who answers!!**

**UPDATE**

Jon found the problem, but since the code change is hidden in comments, I'll copy it here, too.

The problem was that `SimpleDateFormat` is using the system timezone, not the timezone of the given `GregorianCalendar`, like I had assumed. I fixed this by changing this line:

```
return SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance(SimpleDateFormat.SHORT).format(datetime.getTime());
```

to this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", LOCALE);
        sdf.setTimeZone(TIMEZONE);
        return sdf.format(datetime.getTime());
```

Then I removed the `+1` and `-1` from the `TimePicker` and it works!

Comment: I doubt it, but maybe it has something to do with daylight savings?

Comment: Almost certainly daylight savings. If the date/time is being converted to your locale when printing, and you're in the UK, from November to March (more or less) your local time is the same as GMT. But from April to October (more or less) your local time is one hour ahead of GMT.

Comment: @jas and @Felk - I'm not in the UK, I'm in Italy. But yep! I didn't know I had to set the timezone in `SimpleDateFormat`. I feel stupid for not seeing it now (one of the annoying two months of the year where the US has done daylight savings but Italy hasn't and it effects my calendar all month long). I guess I just had it in my head that I'm using GMT and timezones/DST is not my problem. And I was so sure *my* question wasn't another timezone one! Oh well! At least you were all very nice about it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the time zone of the *calendar* you're using, but that's not what you pass into the `SimpleDateFormat` - you're just using the default system time zone when you format here:

```
SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance(SimpleDateFormat.SHORT).format(datetime.getTime())
```

I would suggest that:

- Ideally, move on to Joda Time or `java.time` from Java 8. The `java.util` classes are *awful*. I realize you're working on Android, so `java.time` is out, but is Joda Time an option for you?
- Take the date picker out of the equation: try hard to come up with a short but complete program demonstrating the problem - just a console app which (say) tries to format 5am on the 1st of every month from the start of 2010 to the end of 2019. (Try to reproduce it outside Android, for simplicity.)
- Whenever you format or parse (or do anything, basically), work out exactly what time zone you're interested in, and specify it explicitly. (I'd recommend using `UTC` rather than `GMT` to indicate "no offset from UTC" as otherwise some people will think you mean the UK time zone.)

Comment: They're not THAT awful, though they do require more knowledge than you'd like to. But it is a hard domain to grasp in the first place. In the end the mistake is common but simple: using a SimpleDateFormat with a default timezone.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek: It's a much simpler domain to grasp when the API is appropriate. For example, in Noda Time, we never do *anything* using the default time zone implicitly - you have to *say* when you want the system default time zone, because then even when you do want it, it's clear to anyone reading the code. The number of ways in which `Calendar` and `Date` are bad is huge... I could rant for a *very* long time on this...

Comment: That is actually a nice idea though, never using the default timezone implicitly. The timezone of the machine the application is running on is almost never relevant.

Answer (score 1):

try using this method

```
Date date = new Date();    
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd  HH:mm").format(date));
```